# WAMP server stops form actions? CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, submit, wamp

Key Point: Submit buttons for a form won't work on WAMP server.(Using form helper)
           Works on University server. Doesn't on WAMP server.

I have been creating some simple forms that adds details that are entered into a database on phpMyAdmin. I had a lot of trouble getting the submit button to work on my form but managed to fix it when I ran the site on the University server. It seems that form submit buttons don't work with WAMP servers. Any ideas? 
The button has no response at all on WAMP.

```html
<?php
  echo form_open('site/inputWorker');
  echo form_label('Forename:', 'Forename');
  echo form_input('Forename');
  echo "<br>";
  echo form_label('Surname:', 'Surname');
  echo form_input('Surname');
  echo "<br>";
  echo form_label('Skill1:', 'Skill1');
  echo form_dropdown('Skill1', $skills, 'None');
  echo "<br>";
  echo form_label('Skill2:', 'Skill2');
  echo form_dropdown('Skill2', $skills, 'None');
  echo "<br>";
  echo form_label('Skill3:', 'Skill3');
  echo form_dropdown('Skill3', $skills, 'None');
  echo "<br>";
  echo form_label('Availability:', 'Availability');
  echo form_dropdown('Availability', $availability, 'None');
  echo "<br>";
  echo form_submit('Add Worker', 'Add Worker');
  echo form_close(); 
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for your form?

Comment: I'm sure it's not the code since i've had it working before on a different server.

Comment: Well I'm sure it's not WAMP as such. Something else is going. So what do you actually see happen when you click on the submit button? Running it on another server is Not fixing anything!